# Why are there two sections for Links within a Links List?

Tags: 2013, list, sharepoint-server, hyperlink

I am using SharePoint 2013. I started using the Links List. Why does the Links List have two sections top post a link when I am only posting one link at a time? On the top there is a URL field and on the bottom there is a HyperLink field. It almost looks like ti will allow me to post two links when in fact, (if I am correct), only one link will be posted.
[image: Link List Image]

Comment: That isn't a standard links list, it looks like you have added additional columns of metadata

Comment: You're correct about that. I did add a Date and Time column.

Comment: I did remove the Date and Time from the Link List column. However, the same duplicate link field is still there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have simulated your steps

[image]

and I am pretty sure that you have added new column with `HyperLink and Picture` type that called `HyperLink`, and your requirement will be achieved if you delete  `HyperLink` column instead of  `date time` column  as the following

- Open your list > List Setting > Below columns > find HyperLink column name > click on it.

[image]

- Click delete if you don't need it, it should not be now shown at your new field.

[image]

Comment: I checked. I did not have the HyperLink selected. Thank you for taking the time to answer my questions with the screenshots.

Comment: you are welcome , but I talk about columns with hyperlink data type ? , have you checked your columns ?

Comment: Open your list > List Setting > Below columns > check if you have additional columns or not , it's not related to date time column , as you mentioned at your comments above , it's as Eric mention,

Comment: Thanks. Sorry for not reading your reply correctly. I did go to Open List . List Settings > Below Columns and did find the HyperLink that your screenshot displayed. However, I did not find any Edit Column area. Perhaps that's because the Farm Admin did not enable it?

Comment: @SharePointNY To edit it , click on the column name , to can open edit column , and click on delete to can delete it , please tell me if you need more clarification

Comment: Great , you are welcome